# random generation of list elements with rules

Tags: python, algorithm

Let list *l* consists of *n* elements, where

1. each element should be either 0 or a positive integer less than or equal to *r*, and
2. the sum of list should be equal to *m*

Example:

```
Given n = 5, r = 4, m = 10

l = [4, 3, 2, 0, 1]
```

It is easy to fulfill rule(1), but I wonder if there is any good idea/algo to fulfill both rules?

Comment: What do you intend to do if the conditions are unsatisifiable (e.g., n=5, r=4, m=100)?

Comment: I would just like to point out that the list would no longer be random if you add rules which define how it should be generated.

Comment: Should you require a certain number of 0s? Or elements to be unique? Otherwise, as long as `r<m` and `r*n > m`, I'd just use `r` `floor(m/r)` times, then insert a remainder, then fill with 0s until `n` is satisfied

Comment: how random should it be?

Comment: Excuse me for asking the obvious, but must the result only include positive integers?

Comment: @BrenBarn, the list is invalid and will be abandoned. So the algo should be efficient enough to avoid generation of such list.

Comment: @mike.k, The list elements need not be unique or bounded to certain number of 0s.

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable interpretation would be to (i) find and count all unique lists satisfying the rules; and (ii) pick one of those lists at random with equal probability. The problem with this method is that it is complicated to code the list of lists.

A simpler way to do it (less code) is to expose each correct list to the same probability of being picked.  That algorithm is:

1. **check that `m<=nr`**  If not, return None or raise an error.
2. **Loop:** repeatedly generate lists with random numbers in [0,r]. **Break**  the loop and **return** the first list of sum m.

Note: The tradeoff here for less code is potentially longer execution time. if r is large, or m is an improbable sum, this may take a while. We can mitigate this a little by checking the limits where the answer can only be zeros or `r-1`'s.

```
from numpy.random import randint

def known_sum_random_list(size,limitint,knownsum):
    if knownsum>size*(limitint-1):
        return None
    if knownsum==size*(limitint-1):
        return size*[limitint-1]
    s=0
    l = size*[0]
    while (s!=knownsum):
        l = randint(0,limitint,size)
        s = sum(l)
    return l

for t in xrange(10):
    print known_sum_random_list(5,4,10)
```

output:

```
[3 2 1 2 2]
[1 1 2 3 3]
[3 0 3 1 3]
[3 2 0 3 2]
[2 2 0 3 3]
[1 3 2 3 1]
[3 3 0 3 1]
[2 0 2 3 3]
[3 1 2 3 1]
[3 2 0 3 2]
```

Comment: I think the original question asked for values only less than `r`. Other than that this looks good!

Comment: Yeah I fixed it.  Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple brute force solution. Basically, you want to generate samples where random integers less than `r` are equally likely. Samples that do not meet the criteria (sum to `m`) are rejected.

```
import numpy as np

def rand_with_rules(n, r, m):
    if n*(r-1) < m:
        raise ValueError
    while True:
        l = np.random.randint(0, r, size=(n))
        if l.sum() == m:
            return l
```

Note that the rejection of samples will necessarily bias your "random" numbers. Because of your constraints, you can't have a purely set of random and certain will tend to be over or underrepresented.

Take, for example, the case n, r, m = 2, 3, 4. The only series that matches this criteria is (2, 2), so the likelihood of drawing 2 is 100% and 0% for other values.

In essence, this solution states that you have no prior knowledge of which integers are most likely. However, through the *constraints*, your posterior knowledge of the numbers will almost never be truly uniform.

There's probably a clever analytic solution for the distribution of integers given this constraint, which you could use to generate samples. But I don't know what it is!

Comment: My answer isn't correct! I shouldn't be using a Multinomial at all. I'm trying to come up the right way to do it.

Comment: Doesn't the pymc implement [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) which says multinomial only has support on a selected sum?

Comment: I think I see, the problem here is you have no guarantee the number of "successes" of a particular category (array element) is limited by r

Comment: Ok, I removed the bit about pymc and the multinomial distribution and I think it's correct. This solution is dumb and hackish and definitely won't scale, but it might be good enough for the poster.

Comment: OP said he wants only less than `r`.

Answer (score 0):

Without validation that all rules can be meet at once, I suggest following solution

```
import random

def dis(n,m,r):
  l = [0] * n

  for inc in range(1,m):
    l.sort()
    for ind_less_r, less_r in enumerate(l):
      if less_r > r:
          break
    l[random.randint(0,ind_less_r-1)] += 1

  random.shuffle(l)
  return l


for i in range(1,10):
  print dis(10,50,9)
```

result is

```
[7, 7, 6, 1, 6, 3, 5, 4, 4, 6]
[5, 6, 7, 5, 4, 7, 4, 4, 4, 3]
[4, 3, 2, 4, 7, 7, 5, 7, 5, 5]
[4, 4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 6, 4, 5, 5]
[6, 6, 4, 6, 5, 6, 2, 5, 4, 5]
[2, 8, 4, 2, 6, 5, 4, 4, 6, 8]
[6, 6, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4]
[6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 1, 5, 6, 6]
[4, 5, 4, 7, 6, 6, 3, 2, 6, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you responded in comments that it can have many 0s and numbers can repeat, I infer that it need not be all that random. With that in mind, here is a basic solution without any loops or includes. It assumes `n`, `r`, and `m` have valid values and types. But such checks are simple enough to add, I'll edit them in upon request.

```
def create_list(n, r, m):
    output = [r] * (m/r)
    remainder = m - r * len(output)
    if remainder != 0:
        output += [m - r * len(output)]
    output += [0] * (n - len(output))
    return output

output = create_list(5, 4, 10) # gives [4, 4, 2, 0, 0]
output = create_list(5, 2, 10) # gives [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

<s>P.S. - request was for values less than `r`, but example showed values equaling `r`, so this is going by the example</s>